# How to reduce the number of "I"s in my writing?

Tags: writing

Every time I write a passage, I find I inevitably use "I" again and again! I want to know how I can reduce the number of occurrences of this word in my writing? How can I avoid using many "I" pronouns and use just one instance for more than one sentence?

Comment: Could you give some real examples? It might not be that  bad to write many I's. You could use "my" instead of "I". Take your question for example, you could say "My point is, how ..." or "My question is, how".

Comment: @jinawee's request for examples is spot on; we need to see your writing to answer your question. However, do note that you can't correctly replace *I* with *my* without at least marginally changing the context. Also, one possibility for reducing the frequency of *I* is avoiding phrases like *I mean*, which I have edited out of your question.

Comment: So the authentic writing sample we had has been edited away -- editing is not always a good thing!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original question:

> Every time I start to write a passage, I find myself inevitable to use "I" again and again! I want to know how I can reduce the number of this word in my passage? I mean what kind of ways can I use to link different sentences to each other and use just one "I" for more than one verbs!

Rewritten to avoid excessive use of "I".

> Every time I start to write a passage, I find myself inevitable to use "I" again and again!

The above sentence is fine (as far as "I" is concerned ;) .

> I want to know how I can reduce the number of this word in my passage?

```
How can the frequency of this word be reduced in my passages?
```

> I mean what kind of ways can I use to link different sentences to each other and use just one "I" for more than one verbs!

```
What methods are there to link different sentences to each other and
use just one "I" for more than one verb!
```

Hopefully the above rewrite will be helpful to you.  There are two things to keep in mind when writing:

- we know it's from you, so we can assume that anything said means it's something you think or know or believe or want, so you don't have say I much, if at all
- if the thing you are saying is *not* from you, make sure make that clear:  `according to so-and-so` or `The government has claimed`, etc.
- when you want to use "I", try rewording the sentence/question with the verbs `be` or `are` or `is` instead (these verbs don't go with "I"); if that doesn't work, use "I"